# Float Div To The Left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have this code:

```
<div class="input-append">

    //FIRST ELEMENT 

    <select name="branch_group_limit" id="select_library">
        <option value="">All libraries</option>                               
        <option value="branch:01">Main Library</option>                               
    </select>

    //SECOND ELEMENT

    <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="btn btn-success">Go</button>
</div>
```

And the arrangement of the elements looks like this.

```
FIRST ELEMENT | SECOND ELEMENT
```

But when I tried to customize my first element using Jquery:

```
$('#select_library').parent().append('<div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown"><span data-bind="label">All libraries</span> <span class="caret"></span></button><ul id="newselect_library" name="branch_group_limit" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">');
$('#select_library option').each(function(){
   $('#newselect_library').append('<li value="' + $(this).val() + '" role ="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">'+$(this).text()+'</a></li>');
});
$('#newselect_library').append('</ul></div>');
$('#select_library').remove();
$('#newselect_library').attr('id','select_library');
```

The arrangement of my elements turns out to be:

```
SECOND ELEMENT | FIRST ELEMENT
```

And my HTML Output is:

```
<div class="input-append">

     //SECOND ELEMENT                                    

    <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="btn btn-success">Go</button>

    //MODIFIED FIRST ELEMENT

    <div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown">
            <span data-bind="label">All libraries</span> <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul id="select_library" name="branch_group_limit" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li value="" role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">All libraries</a></li>
            <li value="branch:01" role="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">Main Library</a></li>
        </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what to do to keep it on its original arrangement.Sorry if I couldn't post an image. Anyhelp would be very much appreciated.Thanks.

**SOLUTION:**

I used prepend instead of append in my jquery code.

```
$('#select_library').parent().prepend('<div class="btn-group btn-input clearfix"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle form-control" data-toggle="dropdown"><span data-bind="label">All libraries</span> <span class="caret"></span></button><ul id="newselect_library" name="branch_group_limit" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">');
$('#select_library option').each(function(){
   $('#newselect_library').append('<li value="' + $(this).val() + '" role ="presentation"><a tabindex="-1" role="menuitem">'+$(this).text()+'</a></li>');
});
$('#newselect_library').append('</ul></div>');
$('#select_library').remove();
$('#newselect_library').attr('id','select_library');
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not how you append elements. `.append('</ul></div>')` is absolutely wrong.

Comment: @SalmanA --> Im sorry if it's not. But how should I do it? Can you point me somewhere in the web, that will help me learn the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are appending `newselect-library` to main `div`, this will change their order in dom.
Any `append` action will insert new element after **last** child.

Before append:

```
select_library - searchsubmit
```

After append (add to end of child list):

```
select_library - searchsubmit - newselect_library
```

After removal:

```
searchsubmit - newselect_library
```

Wrap your select_library with a div, so it always comes before button in dom tree.

```
<div class="input-append">

    //FIRST ELEMENT 
    <div class="select-holder">
    <select name="branch_group_limit" id="select_library">
        <option value="">All libraries</option>                               
        <option value="branch:01">Main Library</option>                               
    </select>
    </div>

    //SECOND ELEMENT

    <button type="submit" id="searchsubmit" class="btn btn-success">Go</button>
</div>
```

Comment: CemOzer --> Thank you so much you gave me an idea, however I already tried wrapping my first element with a div ,which has a class "btn-group btn-input clearfix" through jquery modification. But still the 'second element' goes first before the 'first element'.

Comment: Because when you call $('#select_library').parent(), it gives you div with 'input-append' class. It does not matter if you wrap your new element. You must wrap your 'select_library' element with a dummy div in html. Then your parent() call will give you that dummy div not main div.

Comment: That is one way solution,but I solved my problem through using prepend instead of append. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If float : left didn't work try prepend

```
$("button").click(function(){
```

$("p").prepend("**Prepended text**");
});

Answer (score 0):

Set css to your elements as:

```
position: relative:
float: left;
```

That's it;

Comment: -->I'd tried:#select_library{position: relative;   float: left;}  but it doesn't work.

Comment: @AlyssaGono Can you make it as jsfiddle, so that i can take a look at it.